# Small character or image to represent code?

Tags: icon, symbolism

Now I want to put something in a logo which can represent that we do coding or at least signifies coding or something that's related to code

like

```
{ P = () * etc
```

What's the smallest character or symbol (max 3 characters) or anything else which can signify code? I don't have space for an image, I can hold only 1-3 characters

```
(..)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Many icons (including one used at the Stack Exchange sites) representing code are comprised of an empty set of curly braces.

```
{ }
```

Comment: [Programmers.se](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)'s logo works great too: `/* Programmers */` Although comment block expresses more about commentary and the subjective side of coding (which probably is the intent in that case).

Comment: Could also add an ellipsis inside the braces and still remain within 3 character limit.  {&hellip;}  (well, you could if HTML entities worked in comments)

Answer (score 6):

`</>` is most common I think since it represents HTML and some markup languages.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you mean coding as programming. So therefore I can imagine something like `f()` or `a[0]` would be quite nice in relation to modern programming languages. Other ideas, but containing slightly more characters: `int *ptr;`, `void *`.